# ssh could not connect to the server, and disconnected after providing the username. Logs for sshd-ddd and ssh-vvv are provided below

Tags: centos, ssh, glibc

> The original text is in Chinese, translated into English using Google Translate.

### premise

Because of the need to upgrade glibc2.28 to glibc2.29, and later required too many dependencies, the upgrade was given up. Then when connecting through ssh, it is found that the server cannot be connected, and the authentication fails. After connecting through the ssh client of other hosts and entering the user name, it will be disconnected. Below are the logs of ssh-vvv and sshd-ddd.

**ssh-vvv**

```shell
root@centos7 ~/.ssh [255]# ssh 192.168.0.108 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.108" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.108 [192.168.0.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.108:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.108
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lrILn/aJ6YNrgEvD0AmLZLZF0NAwZzHr646xCCPDnJg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.108
debug1: Host '192.168.0.108' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x559cf376ecc0)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Authentication failed.
```

**sshd-ddd**

```shell
612[Mon Jan 30-09:41:03root@file-b85~/.ssh]0#:
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 770
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 770
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:22 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:23 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:24 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:37 setting SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:42 setting LoginGraceTime 9999m
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:43 setting PermitRootLogin yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:52 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:70 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:74 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:84 setting GSSAPIAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:85 setting GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:101 setting UsePAM yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:106 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:113 setting PrintMotd no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:116 setting TCPKeepAlive yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:132 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:133 setting AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:134 setting AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:135 setting AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:138 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.0, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:pTKVjaCxr4EzQP2UjRlWmsqJ5iasRoe6pFG5J2iNL7Y
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lrILn/aJ6YNrgEvD0AmLZLZF0NAwZzHr646xCCPDnJg
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:SeVuB78TP+rR6V/Szag663h80BXTjTzq5lQ+4xxz3TY
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 7 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug3: fd 8 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 11 config len 770
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 8 out 8 newsock 8 pipe -1 sock 11
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Connection from 192.168.0.22 port 46868 on 192.168.0.108 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 1156516
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug1: SELinux support disabled [preauth]
debug3: privsep user:group 74:74 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x55bfcbd542b0(100)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 770
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for root [preauth]
debug3: mm_start_pam entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 100 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authrole entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 80 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.883ms, delaying 6.601ms (requested 7.484ms) [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 100
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.0.22"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 80
debug3: mm_answer_authrole: role=
debug2: monitor_read: 80 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
debug1: Killing privsep child 1156516
```

> I don't think the id_rsa mentioned in ssh-vvv is relevant, because I use this client to connect to other normal sshd servers and it will also prompt this. And I can't connect to this server using other ssh.

```shell
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

### methods tried

1. It is said on the Internet that it is a problem with pam. I changed usepam into no in sshd_config Lane, not good.
2. It has been upgraded with dnf install openssh, but it does not work.
3. I later uninstalled `openssh openssh-server openssh-client` using rpm, and then re-installed did not work.
4. Resetting the ssh_config and sshd_config configuration files to the initial state does not work.
   These files were moved during the upgrade, but I have restored them and compared them with another centos8.4.2105 server, and there is no problem.

```shell
613[Mon Jan 30-09:41:17root@file-b85~/.ssh]255#:
ll /usr/lib64/libnsl* 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 800240 Jan 29 17:44 /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.28.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     14 Jan 29 17:44 /usr/lib64/libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.28.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     15 Jan 29 11:37 /usr/lib64/libnsl.so.2 -> libnsl.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 120592 May 11  2019 /usr/lib64/libnsl.so.2.0.0

614[Mon Jan 30-09:57:09root@file-b85~/.ssh]0#:
ll /usr/lib64/libnss_nis*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Jan 29 17:40 /usr/lib64/libnss_nis.so -> /usr/lib64/libnss_nis.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 May 11  2019 /usr/lib64/libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63536 May 11  2019 /usr/lib64/libnss_nis.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69616 Sep 30  2020 /usr/lib64/libnss_nisplus-2.17.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    33 Jan 28 18:09 /usr/lib64/libnss_nisplus.so -> /usr/lib64/libnss_nisplus-2.17.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    22 Jan 28 18:09 /usr/lib64/libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.17.so
```

Answer (score 1):

## resolved

Due to a problem in the compilation and installation process during the upgrade of glibc, and the parameter specified --prefix=/usr covered some dynamic libraries in the original system, resulting in a system exception.
Later, the same system version was used to start in the crash recovery mode, and the dynamic library in /usr/lib64 was overwritten on the failed server to solve this problem.